# Ring phone on webrtc video call (flutter webrtc)

Tags: flutter, webrtc

Hi I am trying to create a one to one video call in flutter webrtc. It works perfectly, but the second user has to click on the notification ( send through fcm)  which opens the app and then click on a button to join the video call, hence user misses most of the calls  .  I want something like WhatsApp where calling a specific user rings their phone even if the app is in background or killed. Is it possible through firebase messaging, Or flutter webrtc itself?
Please guide me how can it be possible?